# My logging (with robert-hooke) does not work properly with tools.namespace/refresh, why?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

EDIT: Turned out I was using `require` instead of `:require` in the namespace declaration. With `:require`, tools.namespace refreshes the logging namespace, and the problem goes away. I still find it curious, however, that the expression `` (eval `(var ~(symbol "A/func"))) `` does not work in the situation described below (that is, if B below is not refreshed).

Summary: I'm using tools.namespace. If I have namespaces A and B, and in B do `` (eval `(var ~(symbol "A/func"))) ``, and `(tools.namespace/refresh)` and run the code, that works. But if I make a change to A, do `(tools.namespace/refresh)`, so that only A refreshes, then running that expression gives the error: `Cannot resolve var: A/func in this context`, even though `A/func` exists. Why?

Longer version:

In my project, I have a logging module/namespace that uses [robert-hooke](https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke/) (see below). I'm using [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) to reload my code when I make changes.

The problem is the following: When I want to log (my logging currently just prints) something, I list the functions that I want to log in my logging namespace and do `(t.n/refresh)`. That works. But if I make changes to the the namespaces that contain the functions that I want to log, and do `(t.n/refresh)` without making changes to the logging namespace, the logging no longer works (for the functions that have been refreshed). As soon as I make a change to logging, so that it too is refreshed by tools.namespace, it starts working again.

So, it's like the vars in namespaces that have been refreshed don't properly get their logging hooks. But I don't understand why.

Below is my logging namespace. I call `add-logging-wrappers` each time I run my program.

If I add `` (eval `(var ~(symbol "sv/register-damage"))) `` inside `add-logging-wrappers`, that's fine when logging has just been refreshed and the logging works. But those times the logging does not work, that expression causes the error `Cannot resolve var: sv/register-damage in this context`.

```lisp
(ns game.logging
  (require [robert.hooke :as rh]
           [clojure.pprint :as pp]
           [game.server.core :as sv]
           [game.client.core :as cl]
           [game.math :as math]
           (game.common [core-functions :as ccfns]
                        [graphics :as gfx])
           (game.server [pathfinding :as pf]))
  (:use [game.utils]))

(defn log-println [name type object]
  (println (str (current-thread-name) " // " name " " type ":\n"
                (with-out-str
                  (pp/pprint object)))))

(defn print-output [name f & args]
  (let [result (apply f args)]
    (log-println name "output" result)
    result))

(defn print-input [name f & args]
  (log-println name "input" args)
  (apply f args))

(defn print-call [name f & args]
  (println (str (current-thread-name) "//" name))
  (apply f args))

(defmacro make-name-var-list [fn-list]
  `[~@(for [fn fn-list]
        [(str fn) `(var ~fn)])])

(defmacro defloglist [name & fns]
  `(def ~name (make-name-var-list [~@fns])))

(defn add-hooks [name-vars & wrappers]
  (when (seq wrappers)
    (doseq [[name var] name-vars]
      (rh/add-hook var (partial (first wrappers) name)))
    (recur name-vars (next wrappers))))

(defn get-ns-name-vars [ns-sym]
  (-> (the-ns ns-sym) (#(.name %)) ns-interns))

(defn add-hooks-to-ns [ns-sym & wrappers]
  (apply add-hooks (get-ns-name-vars ns-sym) wrappers))

(defloglist log-both 
  sv/distribute-exp     ;; <--- things to log
  sv/register-damage
  sv/give-exp)

(defloglist log-input)

(defloglist log-output)

(defn add-logging-wrappers []
  (dorun (->> (all-ns) (map #(.name %)) (mapcat ns-interns) (map second)
              (map rh/clear-hooks)))
  (add-hooks log-both print-output print-input)
  (add-hooks log-input print-input)
  (add-hooks log-output print-output))
```

Comment: Take your edit at the top and turn it into an answer!